# BibLaTeX: how to cite a multi-volume book whose volumes are called "parts"?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I've recently stumbled upon a multi-volume book whose volumes actually bear the name "part" ([Part I](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-024-0959-8) and [II](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-024-0959-8), for completeness). I'd like to cite it as a multi-volume book. While that is typically very easy with `@mvbook` and its friends, this result usually leads to each volume being called volume. Is there a way to tell `biblatex` that these, and only these, are actually called parts? The "only these" remark is important, because I have other entries that are indeed called volumes. I'd also like to know whether the solution will be dependent on the specific bibliography style or if there is a general solution.

Alternatively, is there a better approach for doing this? Should it be done at all?

MWEB (with current `biblatex` approach and desired result with `thebibliography`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{rudolph2013DifferentialGeometryMathematical,
  title = {Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics},
  author = {Rudolph, Gerd and Schmidt, Matthias},
  date = {2013/2017},
  series = {Theoretical and Mathematical Physics},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location = {Dordrecht},
  langid = {english},
  volumes = {2},
  related = {rudolph2013ManifoldsLieGroups,rudolph2017FibreBundlesTopology},
  relatedtype = {multivolume}
}

@book{rudolph2013ManifoldsLieGroups,
  title = {Manifolds, {{Lie}} Groups and {{Hamiltonian}} Systems},
  author = {Rudolph, Gerd and Schmidt, Matthias},
  date = {2013},
  series = {Theoretical and Mathematical Physics},
  volume = {1},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location = {Dordrecht},
  doi = {10.1007/978-94-007-5345-7},
  langid = {english}
}

@book{rudolph2017FibreBundlesTopology,
  title = {Fibre Bundles, Topology and Gauge Fields},
  author = {Rudolph, Gerd and Schmidt, Matthias},
  date = {2017},
  series = {Theoretical and Mathematical Physics},
  volume = {2},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location = {Dordrecht},
  doi = {10.1007/978-94-024-0959-8},
  langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
%
\bibitem{rudolph2013DifferentialGeometryMathematical}
Gerd Rudolph and Matthias Schmidt. \emph{Differential Geometry and
Mathematical Physics}. 2 parts. Theoretical and Mathematical Physics.
Dordrecht: Springer, 2013–2017.

Part 1: \emph{Manifolds, {{Lie}} Groups and {{Hamiltonian}}
Systems}. 2013.

Part 2: \emph{Fibre Bundles, Topology and Gauge Fields}. 2017.
%
\bibitem{rudolph2017FibreBundlesTopology}
Gerd Rudolph and Matthias Schmidt. \emph{Fibre Bundles, Topology
and Gauge Fields}. Part 2. Theoretical and Mathematical Physics.
Dordrecht: Springer, 2017. \textsc{doi}: 10.1007/978-94-024-0959-8.
%
\bibitem{rudolph2013ManifoldsLieGroups}
Gerd Rudolph and Matthias Schmidt. \emph{Manifolds, {{Lie}} Groups
and {{Hamiltonian}} Systems}. Part 1. Theoretical and Mathematical
Physics. Dordrecht: Springer, 2013. \textsc{doi}:
10.1007/978-94-007-5345-7.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image: Bibliography obtained by the biblatex piece of the code above. The volumes are listed as "Vol"]

Desired result:

[image: Desired bibliography obtained by the thebibliography piece of the code above. The volumes are listed as "part"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below. This solution adds "parts" to the datamodel and changes the `.bib` entries. You could leave them as is and use a sourcemap to change `volumes->parts` and `volume->part` for selected entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Add "parts" to the datamodel as it's not in there by default
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{%
  parts}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{%
  parts}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{rudolph2013DifferentialGeometryMathematical,
  title = {Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics},
  author = {Rudolph, Gerd and Schmidt, Matthias},
  date = {2013/2017},
  series = {Theoretical and Mathematical Physics},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location = {Dordrecht},
  langid = {english},
  parts = {2},
  related = {rudolph2013ManifoldsLieGroups,rudolph2017FibreBundlesTopology},
  relatedtype = {multivolume}
}

@book{rudolph2013ManifoldsLieGroups,
  title = {Manifolds, {{Lie}} Groups and {{Hamiltonian}} Systems},
  author = {Rudolph, Gerd and Schmidt, Matthias},
  date = {2013},
  series = {Theoretical and Mathematical Physics},
  part = {1},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location = {Dordrecht},
  doi = {10.1007/978-94-007-5345-7},
  langid = {english}
}

@book{rudolph2017FibreBundlesTopology,
  title = {Fibre Bundles, Topology and Gauge Fields},
  author = {Rudolph, Gerd and Schmidt, Matthias},
  date = {2017},
  series = {Theoretical and Mathematical Physics},
  part = {2},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location = {Dordrecht},
  doi = {10.1007/978-94-024-0959-8},
  langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[datamodel=\jobname]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{parts}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  parts = {Parts}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{part}{\bibstring{part}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{parts}{#1~\bibstring{parts}}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{volumes}{\printfield{parts}}{\printfield{volumes}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Another way of doing this without modifying the drivers is the following, here we add a custom field to the `.bib` data to tell the `volume/volumes` field formatting that we want parts instead of volumes. You can modify this fairly obviously in the format code to conditionalise on any data in the entries you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Add "parts" to the datamodel as it's not in there by default
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{%
  parts}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{%
  parts}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{rudolph2013DifferentialGeometryMathematical,
  usera = {parts},
  title = {Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics},
  author = {Rudolph, Gerd and Schmidt, Matthias},
  date = {2013/2017},
  series = {Theoretical and Mathematical Physics},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location = {Dordrecht},
  langid = {english},
  volumes = {2},
  related = {rudolph2013ManifoldsLieGroups,rudolph2017FibreBundlesTopology},
  relatedtype = {multivolume}
}

@book{rudolph2013ManifoldsLieGroups,
  usera = {parts},
  title = {Manifolds, {{Lie}} Groups and {{Hamiltonian}} Systems},
  author = {Rudolph, Gerd and Schmidt, Matthias},
  date = {2013},
  series = {Theoretical and Mathematical Physics},
  volume = {1},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location = {Dordrecht},
  doi = {10.1007/978-94-007-5345-7},
  langid = {english}
}

@book{rudolph2017FibreBundlesTopology,
  usera = {parts},
  title = {Fibre Bundles, Topology and Gauge Fields},
  author = {Rudolph, Gerd and Schmidt, Matthias},
  date = {2017},
  series = {Theoretical and Mathematical Physics},
  volume = {2},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location = {Dordrecht},
  doi = {10.1007/978-94-024-0959-8},
  langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[datamodel=\jobname]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{parts}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  parts = {Parts}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{volumes}{\iffieldequalstr{usera}{parts}{#1~\bibstring{parts}}{#1~\bibstring{volumes}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\iffieldequalstr{usera}{parts}{\bibstring{part}~#1}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm just curious about something: is this solution "stable" under change of style? Or does one need to modify the code for each specific style being considered?

Comment: See edit above with another solution which doesn't modify the driver. This will always be dependent on style to some degree as it depends on how they format the volume/part information. However, the second solution above is easier to adapt to different styles without hacking drivers.